# Accessing Functions From Other JS Files - DOJO

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

Im trying to call a function from another js file that is located in the same application directory as my main js script and html file. I receive an error claiming that the referenced function does not exist. I have referenced both of the scripts in the main html file in the proper order but cant for the life of me figure out why it cannot detect the function. I can only assume it has something to do with how dojo parses through the files and have experimented with both its dojo/domReady! and dojo/ready modules in hopes to force scripts to load. I feel like this should be much simpler than Im making it out to be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Asset View</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/esri/css/esri.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href= "styles/styles.css">
        <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/"></script>
        <script src="scripts/requests-js.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/layout-js.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/xmain-js.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class = "claro">

    </body>
</html>
```

requests-js.js

```
require(["dojo/dom","dojo/on","dojo/request","dojo/json","dojo/parser","dojo/ready"


], function(dom,on,request,JSON,parser,ready) {

ready(function() {
    console.log("request start");

    function sendRequest (url,assetCode,fromDate,toDate) {
        console.log("Request innit");
        request(url,{
            method: "POST",
            handleAs: "json",
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            data: JSON.stringify(
                [
                    {
                        "AssetCodes": assetCode,
                        "FromGasDay": fromDate,
                        "ToGasDate": toDate

                    }

                ]
            )


        }).then(function(resp){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
            var naStorageJSON = resp;
        });
    }

    console.log("request end");

});

});
```

main-js.js

```
require([
"dojo/dom","dojo/on","dojo/parser","dojo/json","dojo/request","dojo/ready"

], function(dom,on,parser,JSON,request,ready) {


ready(function() {



    console.log("Main Start");
    var url = "http://*********";
    var assetCode = ["**"];
    var toDate = "****";
    var fromDate ="*****";

    on(dom.byId("senecaLakeBtn"),"click",     sendRequest(url,assetCode,toDate,fromDate));







    console.log("Main End");


});
});
```

Comment: Which function doesn't work?

Comment: the sendrequests inside of the click event listener. Its not supposed to have the "requestsJs" portion before the function call. That is left over from me experimenting.

Comment: removed that portion out to clarify..

Comment: It would seem to me that function is declared within a closure, making it inaccessible from the outside.. is that the problem?

Comment: if it is in a closure it is not being done intentionally. How would one confirm it is not? or in other words, ensure it is made public globally?

Comment: Each function has its own scope, therefore the function `function sendRequest (url,assetCode,fromDate,toDate) {` is not accessible from outside of the `ready(function() {` function. It is, however, hoisted to the top of the scope in which it's declared (because of the method of declaration).

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're coding like this? It seems like you're begging to run into these types of problems when you start sending anonymous functions as the arguments to other functions

Comment: If theres a reason for coding like this its because I do not know any better. Although my thoughts where that the functions would not be anonymous..   If there is a better way I would certainly be interested.

Comment: a function without a name, I.E. `namedFunction( **function() {}** )` is anonymous. And don't blame yourself, without starting from a base of C / C-like languages, it can be hard to tell what 'clear' or 'clean' code is with all the convolution in JavaScript libraries and frameworks these days

Comment: AHA! I think I understand the issue with scope now.

 I was able to get this working (i think) by adding "var app = [];" to the very top of the requests script making it accessible outside of the inner functions.. I then set  the function sendRequest equal to app.sendRequest. Such that: 

app.sendRequest = function sendRequest (a,b,c) {.....}

I can then call it from within other scripts by : app.sendRequest(arg1,arg2,arg3);

Important lesson learned, thanks for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is scope here. By declaring an empty array at the top of the js script (outside of its successive functions) the function can be accessible to other scripts in the application.

```
var app = [];
require(["dojo/dom","dojo/on","dojo/request","dojo/json","dojo/parser","dojo/ready"

], function(dom,on,request,JSON,parser,ready) {

ready(function(){
  app.sendRequest = function sendRequest (url,assetCode,fromDate,toDate) {
...
...
}
}
```

it can them be called upon from other scripts by referencing

`app.sendRequest(arg1,arg2,arg3);`